# System woudn't boot, was it the power supply?

Tags: power-supply

My friend gave my an old server from his work (only reason they gave it to me is because its 8 years old, worked when they had it). When I took it home, I couldn't get the thing to post. I was thinking maybe another friend of mine killed it with static but a few days after I got the server (today) the power supply stopped working. My question is; can a power supply that is going to die soon stop a pc from posting?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Probably if the power supply quit working completely.

Sure, a bad power supply could not turn on at all, or not provide the right power to power up the computer, or could fry something on the computer.

One way to know for sure: Try a different (known good) power supply and see if the system powers up then. Could also try a power supply tester (or multimeter & test wire, though possibly risky, or another computer - also risky if it breaks that computer too) on the suspect power supply and see if it works.

Comment: I'm currently trying to find a power supply that will fit to test in the board, my friend has one that may work